# Feed reader for android, ios with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller, rss-reader

I'm tring to build a rss reader for android, ios platforms with angularjs.

It works, but it reads two times each resource.

[app.js index.html and home.html codes](https://gist.github.com/sakarya/7cc82d3dcaeffdb6be79)

[app demo](http://bs-internet.net/app/#/)

How can I fix it? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `ng-controller='HomeCtrl'` from your `home.html` which is loading your controller twice, As it already loads the controller from route you need not need to mention it on html.

**home.html**

```
<header class="bar bar-nav">
    ..header section..
</header>
<div class="content"> <!--removed `ng-controller='HomeCtrl'` from here-->
    ..markup here..
</div>
```